# Add quotation to each element of a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to use a variable that I've created before in spark to select data from a teradata table:

```
%spark
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true")
val query = "select distinct cod_contrato from xxx.contratos"
val df = sqlContext.sql(query)
val dfv = df.select("cod_contrato")
```

the variable is a string.

So I would like to query the databe usign that vector of strings:

If I use:

```
%spark

val sql = s"(SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in '$dfv') as query"
```

I get:

```
(SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in '[cod_contrato: string]') as query
```

The desired result would be:

```
SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in ('11111', '11112' )
```

How can I transform the vector to a list enclosed by () and with quotation in each element?

thanks

Comment: dfv is yet dataframe, so try to add `.as[String].collect` after `df.select(col)`.

Comment: @Lamanus, thanks but even after this, I still have problems with val sql = s"(SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in '$dfv') as query"

Answer (score 0):

This is my trial. From some dataframe,

```
val test = df.select("id").as[String].collect
> test: Array[String] = Array(6597, 8011, 2597, 5022, 5022, 6852, 6852, 5611, 14838, 14838, 2588, 2588)
```

and so the test is now array. Thus, by using mkString,

```
val sql = s"SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in " + test.mkString("('", "','", "')") + " as query"
> sql: String = SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in ('6597','8011','2597','5022','5022','6852','6852','5611','14838','14838','2588','2588') as query
```

where the final result is now string.

Answer (score 0):

Make a temp view of the values you want to filter on and then reference it in the query

```
%spark
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true")
val query = "select distinct cod_contrato from xxx.contratos"
sqlContext.sql(query).selectExpr("cast(cod_contrato as string)").createOrReplaceTempView("dfv_table"")

val sql = "(SELECT * FROM xx2.CONTRATOS where cod_contrato in (select * from dfv_table)) as query"
```

this will work for the query in spark sql, but will not return a query string. Lamanus's answer should be sufficient if all you want is the query as string